# Duble monitor problem at access

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a projector (hdmi through a display port adapter) connected as a second display and it is correctly detected by Ubuntu together with the first monitor (hdmi) by my graphic card.

The monitor is my main display and I use the projector only occasionally.

I made the displays mirrored and turned the projector off. When I then restarted the computer I couldn't log in because the screen where I type my password was reflected only on the projector and not on the ordinary monitor. I had to turn the projector on in order to see the log on screen.

How do I solve this issue? I tried to make the monitor primary and the projector secondary but I still get the projector as the display where I see the docky and the dash.

In the display menu of the settings the projector is counted as 1 and the monitor as 2. Could this be the reason? How do I change that?

Comment: In those situations all you need to do is move the mouse (yes, a facepalm moment). Then you can and perhaps change the settings so it appears in both.

Comment: After months finally I solved this problem with this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1467005/1418343

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the projector, reconnect it, then sing-in, and from `Display Manager` you can handle this, otherwise - reboot the machine.

Comment: I tried but still even if I make the monitor primary and the projector secondary is always the projector that show the booting screen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching the ports. I put the monitor in the display port adapter and the projector's hdmi directly in the GPU.

Now the monitor is 1 and the projector 2 and I see the boot screen on the monitor instead of the projector.

I didn't think about it because I wanted the monitor to go directly in the GPU with the HDMI and the projector to use the display port adapter. I guess it can't be done. Does it matter?