# Login screen on wrong monitor / display

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, login, display, hdmi

I connected Soundbar system to HDMI port (1), and I connected my monitor to Display Port (2). On windows I can mirror two outputs 3840x1600 and thanks to that have normal display on a monitor via display port and 5.1 audio on a sounbar (ignoring video).
Ubuntu does not allow to mirror outputs at such high resolutions, and forces me to use side by side displays. But Yamaha soundbar is always detected as a first display, and my monitor is always detected as a 2nd display. I'm changing display settings to make 2nd monitor as a primary monitor, but it only works after login. While login the HDMI display is always treated as primary, and invisible because it is sound device :).   How to force HDMI port to be always 2nd / 2ndary display? Or how to mirror 3840x1600 outputs in Ubuntu (Windows allows for it, both cables Display Port and HDMI port are capable of 8K output).

Answer (score 13):

For at least Ubuntu 22.04:

1. Log in and set the monitor layout
2. Check inside the configuration file `~/.config/monitors.xml` if the tag `<primary>yes</primary>` is set in the right monitor.
3. Copy the configuration file from your user to gdm3 folder: `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/`
4. Correct the owner of `monitors.xml` file: `sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml`
5. Reboot

gdm3 config folder is here -> `/var/lib/gdm3/.config`.

user .config folder is here-> `/home/user/.config`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

After you've set your monitors, copy the configuration file `~/.config/monitors.xml` into the folder of your display manager.

For gnome display manager, it would be: `/etc/gdm3/`

For lightdm, it would be: `/etc/ldm/`

This should allow you to set your main monitor to display the login part, not the background.

Comment: This didn't worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04, have you tested it? in which version? Just for curiosity.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'd downvote if I had the points.